# SQL Server Send Mail to Exchange 2016 DAG Gives Certificate Error

Tags: sql-server, exchange

We have an SQL Server 2008R2 installation that was sending email to our now decommissioned Exchange 2010 server.  We are now running an Exchange 2016 DAG with 2 hosts (mailserver1.example.com and mailserver2.example.com) with a DNS pointer called mail.example.com that references both servers.  So, when we took the old server down, we changed from using an actual host name (severname.example.com) to mail.example.com.  When we did this, we get the following error:

```
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2017-02-14T15:41:00). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.).
```

If I change the database mail configuration to point to an individual server in the DAG (mailserver1.example.com) then everything works fine.

We use a wildcard certificate (*.example.com) on the mail servers so I'm not sure if that's the issue.

I would like to fix the issue so that I maintain resiliency.  Can anyone tell me what it doesn't like?

EDIT:
So I dug deeper in to what certificates are installed/being used:

```
Get-ExchangeCertificate -server mailserver2.example.com

Thumbprint                          Services   Subject
----------                          --------   -------
133914D76770DE347949C1FF771A64B7B6  IP.....    CN=mailserver2.example.com
4D2582DA78719BCC1B1CB8F33B3FAC2E54  IP..S..    CN=mailserver2
B39C5DED40D1C926A1ABDA2CA5B30FE305  ....S..    CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
AD3C61F290199AB908ECB976A0C8341351  .......    CN=WMSvc-mailserver2
E6F14092B221239F51A62420FD74F2FA63  IP.WS..    CN=mailserver2.example.com
D1215C7C1E5D674E7C204FCB776D60F93E  ...WS..    CN=*.example.com, OU=PremiumSSL Wildcard, O=Example Company...


Get-ExchangeCertificate -server mailserver1.example.com

Thumbprint                          Services   Subject
----------                          --------   -------
4C560FF28A576F814DFAD198C81912C3BE  IP.....    CN=mailserver1.example.com
B39C5DED40D1C926A1A8DA2CA5B30FE305  ....S..    CN=Microsoft Exchange Server Auth Certificate
A29DA1FA4C800AB5EAD22B0BFA39D7BC5B  IP..S..    CN=mailserver1
184B109C120633C33711E26C40F4FAFFC6  .......    CN=WMSvc-mailserver1
22C69182932BE55A2F01B20C10FADBE359  IP.WS..    CN=mailserver1.example.com
D1215C7C1E5D674E7C244FCB776D60F93E  ...WS..    CN=*.example.com, OU=PremiumSSL Wildcard, O=Example Company...

Get-ExchangeCertificate -domainname example.com

Thumbprint                          Services   Subject
----------                          --------   -------
D1215C7C1E5D674E7C644FCB776D60F93E  ...WS..    CN=*.example.com, OU=PremiumSSL Wildcard, O=Example Company...

Get-ExchangeCertificate -domainname mail.example.com

Thumbprint                          Services   Subject
----------                          --------   -------
D1215C7C1E5D674E7C20D9FF776D60F93E  ...WS..    CN=*.example.com, OU=PremiumSSL Wildcard, O=Example Company...
```

When I use OPENSSL (as per answer 1 below), I am getting our internal CA certificate (CN=mailserver2.example.com) instead of the wildcard cert.

EDIT 2:
Here is the output of the OpenSSL command:
    openssl s_client -connect mailserver1.example.com:25 -starttls smtp

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(000001F4)
depth=1 /DC=com/DC=example/CN=example-Issuing-CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=mailserver1.example.com
   i:/DC=com/DC=example/CN=example-Issuing-CA
 1 s:/DC=com/DC=example/CN=example-Issuing-CA
   i:/CN=example-Root-CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
< certificate info here >
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=mailserver1.example.com
issuer=/DC=com/DC=example/CN=example-Issuing-CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3875 bytes and written 485 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: < session ID >
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: < master key >
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1487248994
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
250 XRDST
QUIT
DONE
```

Comment: Are you also using the wildcard certificate for the Exchange SMTP service (check with Get-ExchangeCertificate -DomainName mail.contoso.com). Additional try to [send an email via telnet (see here)](http://www.admin-enclave.com/de/articles/exchange/352-howto-send-an-email-using-telnet.html) and give us the error message you might get.

Comment: Yes, the same wildcard cert is used.  There is no error when I try and send the email via Telnet though I can't really test SSL email that way.

Comment: Yes and no, you CAN check telnet via an SSL connection if you use OpenSSL. For more infos see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/de/articles/exchange/353-resolved-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.html) or my answer below.

Comment: When I try this, I get the message "WARNING: This certificate will not be used for external TLS connections with an FQDN of 'mailserver1.example.com'
because the CA-signed certificate with thumbprint '4C560FF28A576F814DFAD198C81912C3BE' takes precedence. The
following receive/send connectors match that FQDN: Default mailserver1, Client Proxy mailserver1, Default Frontend
mailserver1, Outbound Proxy Frontend mailserver1, Client Frontend mailserver1."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you see here is related to the SSL certificate used for the SMTP service offered by the MS Exchange environment.

To check the SSL certificate you can use openSSL via:

> openssl s_client -connect exchange01.int.contoso.com:25 -starttls smtp

Depending on the configuration on your MS Exchange environment multiple solutions might apply here (see [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/de/articles/exchange/353-resolved-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure.html) for more infos):

- The hostname isn´t in the SSL certificate (might not the case with your environment)
- The MS Exchange server still used an self signed certificate, you will see that with openssl
- Some SSL certificates used here are outdated
- Some parts from the certification chain aren´t trusted (import the missing one on the trusted root store from the machine as your case it related to SQL services)

**Update (due to your edit):**
It looks like if the SMTP service isn´t using the correct certificate based on your troubleshooting. So the following should nail it down:

```
Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint D1215C7C1E5D674E7C244FCB776D60F93E -Identity mailserver1.example.com -Services SMTP
```

You need to run that for both your Exchange server.

Comment: The error I see (though I'm not sure it's an error) is: "unable to get local issuer certificate".  Would this have an affect?

Comment: No this message is fine, openSSL store there own "root certs" in the certs folder (and something is missing there, maybe your own root) you can simply ignore that openssl message. OpenSSL is only used here to check which SSL certificate is used for starttls. You need to import the mentioned certificates from the chain to your windows OS where the SQL server is running on (in the correct sections). Maybe you can add your openssl response above and xxx sensitive informations.

Comment: Please see the additional information I attached to see if it reveals anything else.

Comment: the used services are not easy to see, but the command _Enable-ExchangeCertificate -Thumbprint D1215C7C1E5D674E7C244FCB776D60F93E -Identity mailserver1.example.com -Services SMTP_ should enable your wildcard cert for SMTP.

Comment: Whoops... Attached the comment to the wrong post: When I try this, I get the message "WARNING: This certificate will not be used for external TLS connections with an FQDN of 'mailserver1.example.com' because the CA-signed certificate with thumbprint '4C560FF28A576F814DFAD198C81912C3BE' takes precedence. The following receive/send connectors match that FQDN: Default mailserver1, Client Proxy mailserver1, Default Frontend mailserver1, Outbound Proxy Frontend mailserver1, Client Frontend mailserver1."  Which is weird because that thumbprint is for a cert that's only valid for IMAP and POP3.

Comment: Hm, you might remove the wrong one (Remove-ExchangeCertificate) or better try to remove the wrong cert from all services via _enable-exchangecertificate -thumbprint 4C560FF28A576F814DFAD198C81912C3BE -services NONE_ then re-try the SMTP one above. Via the none command it isn´t directly deleted on the server (if that works for your Exchange version), its only removed from all connection endpoints, so you didn´t lost the certificate if you need to step back.

Comment: No good... If I do the -Services NONE, I still get the same error when I try and enable the wildcard cert for SMTP (with the SAME thumbprint!).  When I remove the certificate entirely, it then picks the next internally issued cert (22C69182932BE55A2F01B20C10FADBE359 in the case of MailServer1).  It seems Exchange just won't use a wildcard cert as it doesn't think it's a valid FQDN.

Comment: Wildcard certs are [supported](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351044.aspx), so that's not an issue on your side I guess. One another possible idea is to use the GUI and then select the "request a wildcard certificate" option

Comment: The solution turned out to be found here: http://practical365.com/exchange-server/configuring-the-tls-certificate-name-for-exchange-server-receive-connectors/.  It seems that you need to set the TlsCertificateName property on the receive connector if you are using wildcard certificates.  Thanks for all your help!